# How do I generate and print Fibonacci numbers in X10?

Tags: x10-language

I would like to generate and print the first 10 Fibonacci numbers. I don't want to be efficient, but I want to see some (working) X10 code that is easy to understand.

### My try

```
// file Fibonacci.x10
public class Fibonacci {
    public static def fib(n:Int): Int {
        if (n < 2) {
            return n;
        }

        val f1:Int;
        val f2:Int;
        finish {
            async f1 = fib(n-1);
            async f2 = fib(n-2);
        }
        return f1 + f2;
    }

    public static def main(args:Rail[String]) {
        x10.io.Console.OUT.println("This is fibonacci in X10.");
        for (var i:Int=0; i < 10; ++i) {
            x10.io.Console.OUT.println(i + ": " + fib(i));
            fib(i);
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile this, I get:

```
/home/moose/Fibonacci.x10:11: No valid method call found for call in given type.    
          Call: fib(x10.lang.Long)    
          Type: Fibonacci
/home/moose/Fibonacci.x10:12: No valid method call found for call in given type.    
          Call: fib(x10.lang.Long)    
          Type: Fibonacci
/home/moose/Fibonacci.x10:19: Cannot assign expression to target; base types are incompatible.    
          Expression: 0L    
          Expected base type: x10.lang.Int    
          Found base type: x10.lang.Long
3 errors.
```

I use X10 release 2.4.2.

Comment: seems that X10 treats integers as `x10.lang.Long` by default, probably need to explicitly cast them to `Int` whenever necessary?

Comment: I've tried to replace ever `Int` by `Long` - still the same error. My guess was that the call `fib` may be wrong. Eventually it should be something like `this.fib`. However, no matter what I did, I always got errors. (`this.fib` gave me different errors).

Comment: it doesn't make sense to use keyword `this` to invoke static function - `this` refers to class instance and it is the very purpose of static, to be used without class instance :/

Comment: btw, so, what error do you get when you use `Long` instead of `Int`? `Expected base type: x10.lang.Long Found base type: x10.lang.Long` O_o ? no way

Comment: it's a year later, how do you like x10?

Comment: @hellofunk I don't like it at all. I didn't use it very much after this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following version works as expected:

```
// file Fibonacci.x10
public class Fibonacci {
    public static def fib(n:Long): Long {
        if (n < 2) {
            return n;
        }

        val f1:Long;
        val f2:Long;
        finish {
            async f1 = fib(n-1);
            async f2 = fib(n-2);
        }
        return f1 + f2;
    }

    public static def main(args:Rail[String]) {
        x10.io.Console.OUT.println("This is fibonacci in X10.");
        for (var i:Long=0; i < 10; ++i) {
            x10.io.Console.OUT.println(i + ": " + fib(i));
        }
    }
}
```

It seems as if number are `Long` per standard.